# JAVA android Studio method does not overridefrom its superclass

Tags: java, android, onclick, overriding, superclass

I am a beginner in Java development.
I would like to know why I have the error

> "method does not overridefrom its superclass" on the @override declaration.

Here is my code

```
package fr.cif.cif_app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView img = null;
    TextView monTexte = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        img.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    /* Réagir au clic */

        // On récupère l'identifiant de la vue, et en fonction de cet identifiant…
        switch(v.getId()) {

            // Si l'identifiant de la vue est celui du premier bouton
            case R.id.imageView5:
    /* Agir pour bouton 1 */
                break;

            // Si l'identifiant de la vue est celui du deuxième bouton
            case R.id.imageView6:
    /* Agir pour bouton 2 */
                break;

            // Si l'identifiant de la vue est celui du deuxième bouton
            case R.id.imageView7:
    /* Agir pour bouton 2 */
                break;



    /* etc. */
        }

    }
}
```

I have read some other posts which was talking about some errors typing with the name of the function onClick ...but I don't see where is my error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you got 2 errors:

1. `Class cast Exception`:`img.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);`. At this line, you tried to `cast` your `Activity` as an `OnClickListener` but your actually your `Activity` is not. Hence, try to do `implements OnclickListener` with your activity.
2. `method does not overridefrom its superclass" on the @override declaration.` --> that because you try to `override` the `onClick()` method from your father `Activity` class, but you can check your super class, there's no `onClick` method to override.

Anws, in your case, just `implements` `OnClickListener` in your activity is enough.

Comment: Hi Kingfisher, Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your help! it is ok now!